# what is a quick way to import a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a plain text file with a sequence of numbers, one on each line. I need to import those values into a list. I'm currently learning python and I'm not sure of which is a fast or even "standard" way of doing this (also, I come from R so I'm used to the `scan` or `readLines` functions that makes this task a breeze).

The file looks like this (note: this isn't a csv file, commas are decimal points):

```
204,00
10,00
10,00
10,00
10,00
11,00
70,00
276,00
58,00
...
```

Since it uses commas instead of '.' for decimal points, I guess the task's a little harder, but it should be more or less the same, right?

This is my current solution, which I find quite cumbersome:

```
f = open("some_file", "r")
data = f.read().replace('\n', '|')
data = data[0:(len(data) - 2)].replace(',', '.')
data = data.split('|')
x = range(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
    x[i] = float(data[i])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like CSV, so I recommend you take a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: @2rs2ts The remark, "Note that the decimal mark it's a comma and not a dot" leads me to believe these are non-English `reals`, not a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I didn't realize the comma was the decimal separator. If the locale is set right, something like this should work

```
lines = [locale.atof(line.strip()) for line in open(filename)]
```

if not, you could do

```
lines = [float(line.strip().replace(',','.')) for line in open(filename)]
```

---

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]
```

if you want the data as numbers ...

```
lines = [map(float,line.strip().split(',')) for line in open(filename)]
```

- edited as per first two comments below

Comment: Skip the `readlines`. A file-like can be iterated over; `readlines` only causes additional overhead because it builds a list of the file's lines.

Comment: The `readlines()` may be a habit from older versions of Python. I think I still run into cases where it doesn't work without it, but you are right - not been necessary for a long time.

Comment: Thanks @bsoist! I tried the second option, but I had to add a `[0]` to the `map` call (ie: `map(float,line.strip().split(','))[0]`). Still, I have another issue: when some value has some decimals different from zero (eg: `45,05`), I just get the "`floor`" value (ie: `45.0`). I'm looking for a way to get over this.

Comment: I was assuming you had comma separated numbers so I was splitting at the , and applying float to each number. I realize now that , is probably your decimal point, right?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the confussion. I got a way around it anyway (which may not be the most elegant, but it's quite ok).

Answer (score 1):

[bsoist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23247198/2348587) is good if locale is set correctly. If not, you can simply read the entire file in and split on the line breaks (`\n`), then use a list comprehension for replacements.

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()

x = [float(value.replace(",", ".")) for value in data.split('\n')]
```

Comment: @2rs2ts For this case, it's just a little cleaner. You can directly make a list instead of stripping the `\n` of the end of the line during each iteration. Since OP's original code does it, I assumed there aren't performance or memory issues involved in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For a more simpler way you could just do

```
Read = []
with open('File.txt', 'r') as File:
    Read = File.readLines()

for A in Read:
    print A
```

The "with open()" will open the file and quit when it's finished reading. This is good practice IIRC.

Then the For loop will just loop over Read and print out the lines.

Comment: This does not strip the trailing `\n` from each line.

Comment: What's up with the capitalized variable names? They shouldn't be capitalized unless they're classes.

Comment: @Human You can call a variable whatever you like, it's up to the discression of the user not to use preset variables though ( which are 95% lowercase starting such as for list array etc )

Comment: @2rs2ts This was more for simplicity rather than memory saving / speedy / looks fancy.